# Where does the "payload" in the "payload.encoded" come from in a metasploit's exploit?

Tags: ruby, exploit, metasploit

I am analyzing a metasploit exploit [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/linux/ftp/proftp_telnet_iac.rb) and I am trying to figure out where does the `payload` in `payload.encoded` come from on line 358. I am newbie to exploit development but basic programming rules say that `payload` should be initialized before calling any function on it. I don't see `payload` being initialized to any value. There is a `Payload` on line 56 but its first alphabet is capital, so that's something different (Ruby is case-sensitive). That means `payload` is probably inherited from some class. But if its inherited from some class why encode it? Why not fill a new value in it? Especially, I am looking for what is the value that is being taken by `payload` for encoding. It would be a great help if anyone would help me understand that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: The actual payload is generated and encoded by a lower level, i. e., by [`Msf::Exploit::Remote`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/msf/core/exploit.rb) and [`Msf::EncodedPayload`](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/msf/core/encoded_payload.rb). With `payload.encoded` you just get the result of that process.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any value in that code which is being taken `payload.encoded` for encoding?

Answer (score 3):

So, it's Ruby, and the exploit class derives from `Msf::Exploit::Remote`, and that that comes from `msf/core`. Navigate a bit through the code into `lib/msf/core.rb`, and see that it requires from `core/payload`. Open that file:

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/msf/core/payload.rb

Line 179, a function `payload` defined, and you can see that it pulls the payload from `return module_info['Payload'] ? module_info['Payload']['Payload'] : nil`

Back to the original exploit, we see that that is initialized with a `module_info` function and this value:

```
      'Payload'        =>
        {
          'Space'    => 4096,
          # NOTE: \xff are avoided here so we can control the number of them being sent.
          'BadChars' => "\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x20\xff",
          'DisableNops' =>  'True',
        },
```

Some more poking around gives us this in `lib/msf/base/simple/payload.rb`:

```
 payload._import_extra_options(opts)
 framework = payload.framework

 # Generate the payload
 e = EncodedPayload.create(payload,
```

and we find `EncodedPayload` in `lib/msf/core/encoded_payload.rb`, and see that it calls the `generate` method, which is what sets the `encoded` method. Poke around a little more in that file, and we find the `encode` method for generating that. The encoders are pulled from lists of "compatible encoders" which are evidently pulled from the platform (see https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/f0fd2f05983083d84d635d8689237151663902e5/lib/msf/core/payload.rb#L413)

Long story short, the payload comes from `BadChars` above, and it's encoded with an encoder that is platform-dependent.

Comment: I am sorry about "unaccepting" the answer but I came across some web-pages ([here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Metasploit/WritingWindowsExploit) and  [here](http://redstack.net/blog/writing-exploits-for-metasploit-30.html)) which say that `BadChars` is the list of characters the payload should *not* contain. So, I am still not sure about what `payload` contains.

Comment: Ho ho, good catch. Poke around some more in encoded_payload.rb, I evidently didn't peer into it hard enough. My guess is that the payload is either generated on the fly, or stuck into a fixture file somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I did not look around the code in as much detail as A. Wilson did. But when I run exploit in MetaSploit without using selecting any payload (available payloads can be seen with `show payloads` command), it shows before exploiting that the payload being selected is the `reverse handler` (which I guess is the default payload). Looking in the folders of metasploit showed me that the code for this handler can be found in `/opt/metasplot/apps/pro/msf3/lib/msf/core/handler`